# Get the resulting URL from a Leaflet map in R

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm wondering if it's possible to get the final URL of a `leaflet` map in R. I've attempted to get at it with the following, but the URL has placeholders that are filled in, and I'm hoping to get the final URL.

```
library(leaflet)
m = leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(lng=-73.9851, lat=40.7589)

m$x$calls[[1]]$args[[1]][1]
[1] "http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you want to retrieve the URL of the tile where your marker is placed? Programmatically or just once?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to get the URL of the "final" map that is shown in the bounding box after I run the above commands, and I'd like to do this programmatically.

Comment: Maybe I miss something, but realize that there is no "single final URL". Leaflet assembles many tiles, each one having a specific URL, built from the URL template shown in your code. Maybe you are interested in OSM URL for an equivalent map view?

Comment: That might be more in line with what I'm looking for. In my head, I'm envisioning something close to this: `http://www.openstreetmap.org/?#map=16/40.7589/-73.9851`, but would also have my markers and such, and would not include any of the tooltips, menu bars, etc.

Comment: What about using a shiny app containing a leaflet map?

Comment: @mbh86 I'm failing to see how that would help get the URL.

Comment: Just in case you wanted to access it from a web browser. I see your point now, not sure it is possible. Let's see :)

Comment: In all honesty, now that I'm thinking about my problem a bit more, I don't think it's worthwhile at all. There are better alternatives to my final approach that I think might work better, such as using `ggmap`. The goal was to be able to feed the `leaflet` map into `webshot` for converting between HTML output and PDF output. But I might just switch the approach altogether.

Comment: If you are using **knitr** to build your pdf the leaflet map will be converted to a static webshot based plot automatically when you `knit` your document.

Comment: @TimSalabim Yeah, that's what originally led me to ask this question. When it converted the map to a static webshot, it wasn't capturing the full map because some of it hadn't rendered yet. Or so my thought was. My solution, then, was to get the URL and feed that into webshot with a delay. But, at the end of the day, I think the real solution is to just use a non-interactive map when knitting to PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record, if the objective in the end is to produce a static content (such as a printout PDF with a map view), you would probably have much more troubles in going through Leaflet rather than using other R packages that generate static maps with your content (markers, etc.), as you figured out.

Leaflet brings the interactivity functionality (ability to navigate, pan, zoom and interact with features). Which you do not need if you just want a PDF.

Besides, converting Leaflet into a static content (typically through leaflet-image plugin) might still be a pain, depending on the type of user content added on top of the basemap.